DataBricks Auto loader vs Input source files deletion detection
While ingesting files from a source s3 bucket continuously, I would like to be able to detect the case where files are being deleted. As far as I can tell the Autoloader can not handle the detection of files deleted in the source folder. Hence the case can't be supported. I want to confirm that first, and if it is indeed the case, inquire about the approach or work around that people use to handle that scenario. 

Once you detect that an object has been deleted, what are you wanting to happen? Please Edit your Question and add more information about the information flow and behaviour you are seeking.

I’m writing the content of the file in a delta table, and basically, what I would like to do is to delete the content of the file from the delta table.

As an alternative, you could just create an external table that points to this location in Amazon S3. Whenever the table is accessed, Databricks will read the contents of the files in S3. If files are deleted, then the next query to the table will not include the data since it is no longer in S3. If you have a data pipeline (eg using dbt), you could simply select from the external table into a Delta table and the data would exactly match what is currently in S3. No events required.

Thank you. I think I don’t know about the concept of external table, just to make sure can you point me to the right doc so I can do my due diligence on this ?

Found it https://medium.com/@harshavardhan.achyuta/understanding-managed-and-external-tables-in-apache-spark-6e359dd2e5db

Although I am not sure this would work for me. I will need to expand the explanation of the use case better.

According to the Databricks documentation at this time, no, AutoLoader triggers on object creation only (e.g. ObjectCreated events) and therefore does not support detection of deleted files; neither does Databricks Workflows through a means such as File Arrival Trigger.
The ideal solution will depend on what your objective is to do with the deleted files. However, a possible workaround generically speaking would be to create your own AWS Lambda Function that triggers off of the s3:ObjectRemoved:* events (you can trigger Lambda functions using S3 Event Notifications). Depending on what you need to do with the deleted file, you may prefer to do the processing entirely in this Lambda function. Or you may implement the Lambda function to simply copy the file to a different location, which you could have a Databricks workflow process either using AutoLoader or File Arrival Trigger.

(option 1): S3 Event Notification --> Lambda (processing)

This is the leanest, with fewer moving parts and is more cost-effective, but may limit you in terms of processing power and Spark capabilities.


(option 2): S3 Event Notification --> Lambda --> copy file to another S3 location --> Databricks Job processes with File Arrival Trigger

This is more over-engineered since Lambda is already event-driven, but perhaps you need longer processing or capabilities only available on Databricks, so you may still use this option.


(option 3): S3 Event Notification --> Lambda --> copy file to another S3 location --> Databricks Job processes with AutoLoader

This would be ideal if you want to batch process your deleted files from the quarantine, and have access to the full capabilities of Databricks or Spark.




I accept it as it is indeed the solution to the problem as exposed. Thank you for this.

This is actually brillant :) !!! My current architecture is slightly different, but that out of the box thinking will definitively help up, super thanks.

unfortunately on second though it seems that, there will be a problem. To access the file, i would need the file to still be available in the bucket. However this solution would not allow that. So in a sentence, the only thing i see here, is to have a logic to push the object to another folder.
